# React-native Webkit - getting WebKitErrorDomain Code 204 on video for iOS

Tags: react-native, webkit, react-native-ios

We have a website that needs to be ported to mobile app. We have used react-native and the webkit view.

In the website, there is a play button that will open up a video. On Android, this works very well. However, it is not the same for iOS.

Please see error message

```
    Error Loading Page
  Domain: WebKitErrorDomain
     Error Code: 204
 Description: Plug-in handled load
```

Otherwise, the website looks good on iOS. On Android, the video opens and runs smoothly.

We have used this code in the app which is extremely simple.

```
<WebView
     source={{uri: 'http://www.domain.abc'}}
     bounces={false}
     scrollEnable={false}
   />
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try checking as a sample if an image loads from that domain in your app.

Comment: @PritishVaidya, images are loading properly. It is only the video which isn't working on iOS but it works fine on Android. It is a website which only has images as well.

Comment: Okay, then the issue should be with the player.

Comment: @PritishVaidya, Yes. Also agree that issue is with iOS player. Is there anything that can be done to change default player that is being used in iOS?

Comment: I dont know much about that stuff.

Comment: Have you found anything about this?